# How can I update my app on sharepoint store as well as in my website?

Tags: sharepoint

I have made an app on sharepoint and have registered in sharepoint store. Now how can I update my app on sharepoint store as well as the website in which I am using that app?
And what component for an app does it needs to get updated?

I am searching for a solution for past 3 days, but no website has a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint Store should function the same way the AppCatalog does for enterprise applications.  Once the update to your app was accepted and published in the Store, you should be able to update your app on its parent site as follows:

1. Navigate to the site containing the app.
2. Click the gear in the top right of the page.
3. On the dropdown menu that pops up, click "Site contents".
4. On the page that loads, locate your app and hover over the name of the app.
5. Three vertical dots should appear to the right of the app name.  Click the three dots to show actions.
6. On the popup window, click "Details".
7. If the new version has been published by the Store, the "ADD IT" button should light up.  Click it and then wait for the update to complete.

[image]