# How to update existing SharePoint App from App Store?

Tags: sharepoint, app-store, sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepointframework

I am using SharePoint Online. I have installed one app from SharePoint App Store.

After some days publisher launched a new version of that app, but I am unable to update that app with the new version.

Updated version in the SharePoint store

[image: Updated version is available in the SharePoint store]

Installed version in the SharePoint site

[image: Currently installed version in the SharePoint site]

Also, I have found below link,

[How can I update my app on sharepoint store as well as in my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75319186/how-can-i-update-my-app-on-sharepoint-store-as-well-as-in-my-website)

But there is no Update or Get It button to update the SharePoint app from the store in my SharePoint site.

How can I update the SharePoint app with the new version that is available on the SharePoint store on my SharePoint site?